Migrate automapper 8 to 13 with custom resolver implemenation
I have custom resolver for automapper written with automapper 8, after moving to 13 I started noticing below error.
How to fix this ? where to look for getting existing mapping inside customer resolver ?
public string Resolve(TSource source, TDestination destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context) {
 //below part has broken as ConfigurationProvider seems no longer part of ResolutionContext 
 var tp = context.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();

}


Why would you need that? What are you trying to achieve?

I do have some logic that check for mapping , which is my I need to mimic it in new version as well. all test cases failing due to breaking changes

Need to inject IMapper to custom resolver and
var tp = _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.Internal().FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();

